# More nodes than I should

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

Everytime I add 1 SKShapeNode, my total number of nodes shown in the simulator increases by 2. Is this a normal behaviour or should I get rid of the extra nodes, and how ?
I'm on xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1

```
    import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y:self.frame.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(circle)
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get one node for the circle and one node for the filling of the circle. Try removing `circle.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()`. Now the number of nodes only increases by 1.

Comment: That was clarifying. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything else (out of the ordinary) then just assume this is normal. Sprite Kit adds more nodes internally, for instance a SKLabelNode also has subnodes (for the label or individual letters) that you don't have any control over.